# rounding to a specific 12hr timeframe in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I realize this may have been answered before, and I may just not be searching for the answer properly, so my apologies if this is a duplicate. This is for a c# webform.

I've got a datetime, set to now, and rounded up the nearest 30 minutes:

```
DateTime dtNow = RoundUp(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
```

I'm splitting the datetime into its component parts, using M:YY tt (no preceding 0 on the month, two digit year, 12 hr am/pm)

```
  DateString = dtNow.ToString("M/dd/yy");
  TimeString = dtNow.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

What I want do to is simple, I want to see if that TimeString falls between 7:00pm and 5:59am, just need to round it to 6:00am of the following day (unless its past midnight, in which case 6:00am of that day).

Can anyone help me out, or at least point out where its already answered?

Comment: Woulsn´t it be easier to work with dtnow.Hour first, do your stuff and the convert to strings?

Comment: Well suppose that DateTime.Now is 10-3-2017 05:58 am then you want to 'round up' to 10-4-2017 06:00 am ?

Comment: No, sorry if that was confusing. If its 10-3-2017 7:01pm -> 11:59pm, round to 10-4-2017 6:00am. if its 10-4-2017 12:00am -> 5:59am, round to 10-4-2017 6:00am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really stick to `DateTime`. What you want using `string` will always need to parse again that string into a `DateTime` to implement your logic.

A simple solution:

```
public static DateTime GetRoundedDate(DateTime originalDate)
{
    if(originalDate.Hour > 19)
        return originalDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(6);
    else if (originalDate.Hour < 6)
        return originalDate.Date.AddHours(6);
    return originalDate;
}
```

So now you may call:

```
DateTime dtNow = RoundUp(DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
var rounded = GetRoundedDate(dtNow);

DateString = rounded.ToString("M/dd/yy");
TimeString = rounded.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just look at the time properties on your `DateTime` object.

```
if (dtNow.Hour >= 19 || (dtNow is tomorrow && dtNow.Hour <= 7)) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

where "is tomorrow" is something like `dtNow.Date == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dtNow is tomorrow"?

Comment: So by not just giving him the answer and instead trying to help him along, I get downvoted? Thanks SO.